# Ubercart Price based on Weight

Tags: ubercart

**What I need:**

I have a Drupal + Ubercart setup, with one product and different attributes. I need prices calculated by weight attribute, displayed on the cart page & carried through to checkout. I've found numerous attempts at this as results in the past, but no-one seems to have posted their solution. Here are some example figures:

```
250g:$10
500g:$19 #+9
750g:$27 #+8
1000g:$34#+7
1250g:$44 #notice, $34 + $10. Starts again.
1500g:$53
1750g:$61
2000g:$68
2250g:$78 #notice, $68 + $10
2500g:$87
```

**What I have:**

After a lot of searching, I found this module:
https://drupal.org/project/uc_custom_price

In python, this would be easy:

```
total_weight = price = thousands = hundreds = 0

for item in cart:
    total_weight += item[item.index("weight")]
if len(total_weight) > 4: 
    print "Contact wholesales dept. for discounted rate."
if len(total_weight) == 4: thousands = int(str(total_weight)[0])
hundreds = int(str(total_weight)[1])

price += thousands * 34
if hundreds == 7:
    price += 28
if hundreds == 5:
    price += 19
if hundreds == 2:
    price += 10

print price

>> total_weight = 1500
>> 53

>> total_weight = 5750
>> 198
```

Any ideas on how I could do this with Ubercart, Drupal & PHP?

Comment: Why price increase "resets" after 1000g? is it just a maximum container you have? If so, I think it would be both simpler and more honest to add product variants (250g, 500g, 750g, 1000g) and allow multiple in one basket (that's default anyway, isn't it?). That way buyer would know exactly what he will get. Now, it seems you know the algorithm, and you have a field for plain PHP. If you don't want how does `$item` look like, use [devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module and it's `dpm` or `dpr` functions. If you can't use PHP, you are on the wrong site, sadly :(